# Fixing a trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I need a trigger (or two) and I'm doing something wrong.  Or maybe I need to tweak my code.

I want an email to send automatically when I update a line in my spreadsheet.  The three columns that update are notes, status, and resolution.  Right now, in my test version, it sends an email as soon as I change any one of those columns. Which is fine, if I'm only updating one thing. But if I want to add a note, change the status, and enter a resolution all at once, it sends three separate emails. My first trigger for sending an email upon form submission works great.

Here is my code.  Any help would be appreciated

PS:  I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this, but I'm familiar with this from the past. It's just been long enough that I don't remember all of it.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[3];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Set the status of the new ticket to 'New'.
  // Column F is the Status column
  sheet.getRange("F" + lastRow).setValue("New");

  // Calculate how many other 'New' tickets are ahead of this one
  var numNew = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange("F" + i).getValue() == "New") {
      numNew++;  
    }    
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
                    "Helpdesk Ticket #" + lastRow, 
                    "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
                    "working on it as soon as possible. You are currently " +
                    "number " +
                    (numNew + 1) + " in the queue. \n\nHelp Desk.",                    
                    {name:"Help Desk"});
}​

function emailStatusUpdates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var userEmail = sheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue();
  var subject = "Helpdesk Ticket #" + row;
  var body = "We've updated the status of your ticket.\n\nStatus: " + sheet.getRange("F" + 
row).getValue();
  body += "\n\nNotes: " + sheet.getRange("E" + row).getValue();
  body += "\n\nResolution: " + sheet.getRange("G" + row).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"Help Desk"});  
}   

function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"},
              {name:"Schedule Appointment", functionName: "scheduleAppointment"},
              {name:"Push to KB", functionName: "pushToKb"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus);   
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are using an on edit trigger to send and email that works OK when you only need to edit one cell but when you need to edit two or more the email should be sent until you ended to edit all the related cells.

One way to achieve the desired behaviour is to add one or more conditions to send the email.

One way to implement the above is to add an auxiliary column to set if the email should be sent inmediately or not. What about calling this "Hold" and add a checkbox?

This is just is a brief example of how to implement the above as an installe on edit trigger

```
/**
 * Columns C,D,E are notes, status and resolution respectively
 * Column F is Hold
 */
function sendUpdate(e){
   if(e.range.columnStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart < 6 || e.range.columnStart === 6){ 
     var hold = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).getValue(); 
     if( hold !== 'TRUE'){
        // Call here your send email function
     } else {
        // Ask if the email should be sent now
     }
   }
}
```